# cocos2d getting a sprite to blink, it becomes invisible

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

im trying to make my sprite blink, but it just disappears, i have searched google, but i cant find a solution, heres what im doing:

```
    CCBlink * blinker = [CCBlink actionWithDuration: 0.5 blinks: 1];  
 [player runAction: blinker];
```

this method is called when two of my sprites collide, when the collision takes place, i want the 'player' sprite to blink for a few seconds. at the moment, when the sprites collide, the 'player' sprite becomes invisible....thanks

Comment: You should accept an answer or comment.

Answer (score 3):

CCBlink seems to work by toggling the visibility of your sprite on and off a given number of times within the stated duration you gave it. Depending on the duration you set, you *might* sometimes end up with an "off" visibility state at the end of the action (very buggy yeah, I had that too before), which isn't quite desired.

Two suggestions:
(1) Play around with the number of blinks.
(2) Always force the sprite to be visible at the end of the blink:

Add: [CCShow action] to the end of your blink action. You can string both actions into a CCSequence.

Comment: +1 this works. just what i needed. (funny that i came across this two weeks ago when i suggested to OP to accept an answer, and now i use it)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that when (and where) you process 'onCollision' types of events you do not remove the sprite from its parent.

Comment: yep, when the sprites collide, nothing happens, i only want the player sprite to blink, so i have put the above code in the `if (if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, rockRect)0`

Answer (score 0):

Blink action is buggy. I always use the following to guarantee that the object remains visible at the end of the animation:

```
Sequence* action = Sequence::create(Blink::create(BLINK_DURATION, BLINK_TIMES), Show::create(), NULL);
```